# IndexOutOfBoundsException When Incrementing ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am stuck on an issue that's come up on my coding assignment. We have been tasked to read in two txt files based on traffic data and then create objects for each state in the U.S containing a state ID code, the state name and the amount of traffic accidents at each state.

I believe that my code is almost entirely correct, but I keep getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to print my final product, which is every object in my arraylist.

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class OuterMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException{

        String line;

        ArrayList<StateAccident> stateData = new ArrayList <StateAccident>();


        File file = new File("StateCode.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);


        br.readLine();
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){

            String arr[] = line.split(" ");
            int stateCode = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);   
            String stateName = arr[1];
            StateAccident accidents = new StateAccident(stateCode,stateName);
            stateData.add(accidents);


        }

        File stateAccidentsFile = new File("StateAccidents.txt");
        fileReader = new FileReader(stateAccidentsFile);
        br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        line = null;

        br.readLine();  
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){ 

            String arr[] = line.split(" ");

            int stateID = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);

            stateData.get(stateID-1).incrementAccidentCount();

        }   


        for(StateAccident accidents : stateData){
            System.out.println(accidents.toString());
        }



    }

}
```

The line that is giving me the error is:

```
stateData.get(stateID-1).incrementAccidentCount();
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this because I feel that it's a simple fix, but I've been stumped on it for hours and don't really know what else to try.

Here are the two text files that I am reading from:

Statecode.txt: https://pastebin.com/LCRLystK
Stateaccidents.txt: https://pastebin.com/bDGDu4UQ

If there is any other information that I can provide to help you, please let me know!
This is my first post so I apologize if there are any mistakes in my question, I will be sure to correct them if need be. 
Thank you!

Comment: You have a flaw in your approach - the states file does not list all states in a sequential order - it's missing code=7 for example so there are only 54 entries in the array (0..53) - the accident file on the other hand has entries for stateid=56 which results in 55 and there is no entry for 55.  IF you need more explanation I can post an answer.

Comment: @Andy I would appreciate some help. I have been googling forums for awhile and I can't quite figure out how to accomplish the intended result. If it's not too much trouble I would really appreciate it. I've been stumped on this for awhile.

Comment: I'd try one slight change - I'm not able to test it out but...the ArrayList.add has a second form which allows you to put the object in the slot of choice - so when you `stateData.add(accidents);` instead do `stateData.add(stateCode,accidents);`. And get rid of the "-1" in the `stateData.get`.  This still assumes the statescode data is in increasing order however so that would be a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble you're having is that the `ArrayList.get` method is index based, and you're using a value *calculated* from the state id, which is not guaranteed to actually be the index.

In fact, if you look at the Statecode.txt, it's missing state id 3.  So state id 1 is at index 0, and it happens to work.  State id 4 though is at index 2, which is, going to cause confusion.  As you get down the list, there are more missing, so State id 56 is at index 53 (guessing a bit there). So when you do `get(stateId -1)` for state #56 it does `get(55)`, which is, in fact, beyond the length of the ArrayList.

So you need to find a different way to get the accident count for the state. A few options I can think of:

- For each accident row, you could loop through all of the state records to find the one that has the matching state id.  I don't like this idea much.
- Doctor your statecode.txt data so your reference works (so add a state 3, with name 'unkown').  It's a bad idea to doctor your input data, and also a bad idea to expect a complete set of data.
- Use a different sort of collection.  This is what I'd do, probably a java.util.Dictionary

Comment: Would it be possible that you could show me an example of what you'd do with a java.util.Dictionary? I've actually never heard of that before (I'm pretty new) and I'd like to see how you would implement it in this case. Do I have to change large portions of my code, or is it just that one line that I need to adjust?

Comment: `Dictionary` is not a good suggestion.  Its javadoc says up front that it is obsolete.  You should be using a `Map` class; e.g. `HashMap`

Comment: For beginner information on Maps, refer to the Oracle tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html

Comment: As for "show me examples of using `Map`" or other tutorials on this (if the above are too advanced) ... Google will be able to find some for you.  But "write an example just for me" is a step too far.

Comment: @StephenC I apologize. I'm in an intro java course and had never heard of it before, I was hoping that there was just a simple solution to my problem. I will try to do some research on map and attempt to solve this, thank you for the advice.

Comment: No it is not a simple one-line change.  Sorry.